Docker-compose watch sync action doesn't work
I am trying to set up hot-reload in my next.js project. I was following instructions from official docker documentation and it all doesn't seem to work.
Here is my setup for app service:
app:
    container_name: app
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./pages/
          target: /app/pages
          ignore:
            - node_modules/

pages is a directory where _app.js is stored. Containers run perfectly fine with docker compose up --watch command and all changes are even detected by docker, I can see it in the terminal. But they don't seem to be applied and not visible on localhost.
This is the screenshot of terminal message.
Maybe anyone has any ideas about what did I do wrong? It works if I will change sync to rebuild. But as follows from the documentation sync should be enough for hot-reload.
